# Remove List from session in JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl

I would like to set the List to null in jstl but the `<c:remove>` tag i used throws

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException

What is the proper syntax to set the list to null?

Thanks in advance

```
<c:if test="${ not empty recList }">
    <table>
        <c:forEach items="${ recList }" var="charge">
            <tr>
                <td>${ charge.value }</td><td>${ charge.name }</td><td>${ charge.description }</td>
            </tr>       
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
    <c:remove var="${ recList }" scope="session"/>  
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The var attribute in c:remove is the name of the variable, it shouldn't be an EL expression.

```
 <c:remove var="recList"/>
```

See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_remove_tag.htm

Answer (score 2):

you should use like this 
 `<c:remove var="recList"/>` not with the Expression
Cheers